# Need to insert space between inline elements

Tags: html, css

I need to insert a dummy space between multiple span elements. ie; Need to insert a space between "Help" and "Feedback"

How can I do that?

http://jsfiddle.net/hsQ24/

HTML:

```html
<div id="header">
  <span>Help</span>
  <span>   </span>
  <span>Feedback</span>
  <span>help</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
#header {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: `&nbsp;` is very impractical. Padding would do a much better job and much more practical than manually inserting space after every span.

Comment: @MLeFevre having to repeatedly add `&nbsp;` wherever you want spacing is bad practice. CSS lets us do this with `margin`.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly Didn't read the question carefully to realise he'd want more than once. I'd agree with using a CSS solution if that were the case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can use the `:before` pseudo-element as well. Check the **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/hameyacu/1/edit)**.

**CSS like**

```css
span:before {
  content: " "; 
  display: inline-block; 
  width: 32px;
}
```

**HTML Code**

```html
<div id="header">
  <span>Help</span>
  <span>   </span>
  <span>Feedback</span>
  <span>help</span>
</div>
```

In Addition, if need to remove unnecessary span you can use `:nth-of-type`

```css
#header span:nth-of-type(2) {
  display: none;
  background-color: green;
}
```

Another **[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/payetode/1/edit)** link.

Answer (score 9):

Give your `span` elements left and right [`margin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin):

```css
#header span {
    margin: 0 10px;
}
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/hsQ24/2/).

If you're wanting to only add a space between the first and second `span` elements (ignoring the empty one in your example), you can make use of the `:first-child` selector to apply `margin-right` to the first `span` only:

```css
#header :first-child {
    margin-right: 20px;
}
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/hsQ24/7/).

Alternatively you can modify your HTML to give your first `span` element a `class` which can be used instead of the `:first-child` selector.

Comment: Using margin would ignore typographic settings. For example, 10px might be too much space for a 12pt font and way too little for an 80pt font. Using a pseudo class and the content property solves this problem.

Answer (score 4):

Use regular spaces or `&nbsp;`

http://jsfiddle.net/Quadraxas/hsQ24/5/

Answer (score 2):

You can use `padding`

```css
span {
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
```

..or just `padding-right`

Answer (score 1):

If you just want space before that specific element, give it a class and style that:

```html
<div id="header">
    <span>Help</span>
    <span class="feedback">Feedback</span>
    <span>help</span>
</div>
```

```css
#header{
    background-color:red;
}

.feedback {
    margin-left: 1em;
}
```

Updated example: http://jsfiddle.net/hsQ24/4/

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your elements inside a container then use [CSS GRID](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/), [course](https://cssgrid.io/) and then use `grid-gap:value` that was created for your that specific purpose

```css
span{
  border:1px solid red;
}
.inRow{
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:repeat(auto-fill,auto);
  grid-gap:10px /*This add space between elements, only works on grid items*/
}
.inColumn{
  display:grid;
  grid-template-rows:repeat(auto-fill,auto);
  grid-gap:15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="inrow">
  <span>1</span>
  <span>2</span>
  <span>3</span>
</div>
<div class="inColumn">
  <span>4</span>
  <span>5</span>
  <span>6</span>
</div>
```

As for your problem, you should use the row example

Answer (score 0):

```
span {
    padding-right: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For parent `div`:

```css
display: inline-table;
```

Answer (score -1):

I think `&nbsp` is the best answer for what you're searching, if you don't use divs to "store" that menus.

http://jsfiddle.net/AlphaCrack/hsQ24/8/